# can pip freeze show optional dependencies (square brackets)?

Tags: python, pip

I notice that if I install a package with optional dependencies (setup.py extras_require):

```
$ pip install mypackage[optional]==1.0.0
```

I do not see the optional dependency in the output of `pip freeze`:

```
$ pip freeze | grep mypackage
mypackage==1.0.0
```

However, I'm using a requirements-to-freeze workflow that involves using `pip freeze` to update the requirements file with exact versions I use in production. So, what I would like to see is:

```
mypackage[optional]==1.0.0
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

*Update:*
Someone pointed out to me that I actually don't need this in the requirements-to-freeze workflow. In that workflow (at least the version I'm using), you first run `pip install -r requirements-to-freeze.txt`, which has `mypackage[option]`. This will find the latest version and also install the optional dependencies. Later, when `pip freeze` is run, the optional dependencies will be in the list. So actually, the fact that `mypackage` shows up in `pip freeze` without the square bracket notation is fine. The desired outcome will still be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

According to the pip freeze [documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_freeze/), there is no option to do such that thing

Comment: Yes, I started with the documentation and saw no option for that. Also searched around a bit but found nothing. Only came to SO after that. However, someone has now pointed to me that actually what I was asking for is not necessary in the frozen requirement workflow that I'm following. Will update the question.